# Why do items in TreeViewItem inherit the event handlers of parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, treeviewitem

So, I create a TreeViewItem (parentNode), and I add TreeViewItems into the parentNode TreeViewItem. I then add a MouseButtonEventHandler to the parentNode, and now all the TreeViewItems inside parentNode have the MouseButtonEventHandler. I've run the debugger to see if I have code that was accidentally written to add the MouseButtonHandler, but there isn't...

Edit: I did additional tests, and it even goes two levels down. Is there a way to isolate eventhandlers to only the specific node and not its children and/or parents?

```
public newClass() {
    TreeViewItem parent = new TreeViewItem();

    TreeViewItem childOne = new TreeviewItem();
    addExpandClickListener(childOne);

    TreeViewItem childTwo = new TreeviewItem();
    TreeViewItem childThree = new TreeViewItem();


    childTwo.Items.Add(childThree);
    childOne.Items.Add(childTwo);
    parent.Items.Add(childOne);
    TreeViewObject.Items.Add(parent);
}

private void addExpandClickListener(TreeViewItem item) { item.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(item_MouseClick); }


private void item_MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    // Define click event as handled
    e.Handled = true;
    if(sender != e.Source) return;
    // Handle click event
    TreeViewItem root = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    if(root.IsExpanded == true) CollapseRecursive(root);
    else root.IsExpanded = true;
    //else root.ExpandSubtree();
    ViewTree.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: In which place(s) you call addExpandClickListener method? Give us that code

Comment: @Dusan Added code that calls addExpandClickListener method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the parentNode includes the areas of the children. Think of overlapping rectangles. If you only want to have a click to work for the text part, you'll either have to supply your own DataTemplate or use the visual tree to find the header and apply the click to that.

Comment: What do you mean "the text part".

Comment: A treeview item is broken into multiple parts. The plus/minus, the header or text, and the children. Think of it like an expander where the plus controls the visibility of the children. By default the header is a string, but could be anything, i.e a UserControl, a button, etc.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I ended up using a TextBlock and added text to it, and added a click event handler to the TextBlock and adding that to the Header.