# WPF C# TreeView child inherits root event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I've got TreeView:

```
+Guitars
-+Electric
--+Normal
--+Bass
-+Acoustic
```

In XAML:

```
    <TreeView Name="GuitarClassTreeView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Guitars" MouseUp="TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Guitars">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Electric" MouseUp="TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Electric">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Normal" MouseUp="TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Normal" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Bass" MouseUp="TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Bass" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Acoustic" MouseUp="TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Acoustic"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

On each node I added another event to show corresponding list in DataGrid, but only event from main node works. Why?

EDIT:

Functions:

```
    private void TreeViewItem_MouseUp_Guitars(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearGrid();
        guitarGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
    }
```

Every another function is the same, but it has different list as source.

Comment: Could we see the code please?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The area of root node includes the areas of children nodes. Think of overlapping rectangles. If you only want to have a click to work for the text part, you'll either have to supply your own DataTemplate, e.g. adding a TextBlock and using its own events.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334651/why-do-items-in-treeviewitem-inherit-the-event-handlers-of-parent?answertab=votes#tab-top).